# String coverage optimization in Python

Tags: python, string, optimization, functional-programming, python-itertools

I have this initial string.

```
'bananaappleorangestrawberryapplepear'
```

And also have a tuple with strings:

```
('apple', 'plepe', 'leoran', 'lemon')
```

I want a function so that from the initial string and the tuple with strings I obtain this:

```
'bananaxxxxxxxxxgestrawberryxxxxxxxar'
```

I know how to do it imperatively by finding the word in the initial string for every word and then loop character by character in all initial string with replaced words.

But it's not very efficient and ugly. I suspect there should be some way of doing this more elegantly, in a functional way, with itertools or something. If you know a Python library that can do this efficiently please let me know.

**UPDATE**: Justin Peel pointed out a case I didn't describe in my initial question. If a word is 'aaa' and 'aaaaaa' is in the initial string, the output should look like 'xxxxxx'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

words = ('apple', 'plepe', 'leoran', 'lemon')
s = 'bananaappleorangestrawberryapplepear'

x = set()

for w in words:
    for m in re.finditer(w, s):
        i = m.start()
        for j in range(i, i+len(w)):
            x.add(j)

result = ''.join(('x' if i in x else s[i]) for i in range(len(s)))
print result
```

produces:

```
bananaxxxxxxxxxgestrawberryxxxxxxxar
```

Comment: The only problem I see with this is the following use case: one of the words is 'aaa' and the string s = 'aaaaa'. This method would give the result of 'xxxaa' rather than 'xxxxx' because `finditer` finds the next non-overlapping match. Probably won't come up, but it depends on what the OP wants this for.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't clear to me what should happen with overlapping instances of words either.

Comment: @Justin I didn't think of that case, but in the case of the string 'aaaaaa', the word 'aaa' should give 'xxxxxx'. But that really is a corner case, I could live with 'xxxaa' if there is anything better.

Comment: @jdnavarro: the real question is, for string 'aaaa', should the word 'aaa' give 'xxxa' or 'xxxx'?

Comment: @Ned @jdnavarro there's an edge case problem for my solution as well. It isn't clear if the solution really has to deal with these edge cases. If I change my solution to check each word rather than making a combined pattern for all of them, then it should handle all cases... Or of course use the `search` method of a compiled pattern in this question (with an index as per my solution). I guess it depends on what the solution needs to be able to handle.

Comment: @Ned for for 'aaaa' the word 'aaa' should give 'xxxx'. But that's a edge case, I can live with 'xxxa'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer. There might be a faster way to replace the letters with x's, but I don't think that it is necessary because this is already pretty fast.

```
import re

def do_xs(s,pats):
    pat = re.compile('('+'|'.join(pats)+')')

    sout = list(s)
    i = 0
    match = pat.search(s)
    while match:
        span = match.span()
        sout[span[0]:span[1]] = ['x']*(span[1]-span[0])
        i = span[0]+1
        match = pat.search(s,i)
    return ''.join(sout)

txt = 'bananaappleorangestrawberryapplepear'
pats = ('apple', 'plepe', 'leoran', 'lemon')
print do_xs(txt,pats)
```

Basically, I create a regex pattern that will match any of the input patterns. Then I just keep restarting the search starting 1 after the starting position of the most recent match. There might be a problem though if you have one of the input patterns is a prefix of another input pattern.

Comment: If you know how to take care of the 'xxxa' edge case, please let me know your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're restricted to working without stdlib and other imports:

```
s1 = 'bananaappleorangestrawberryapplepear'
t = ('apple', 'plepe', 'leoran', 'lemon')
s2 = s1

solution = 'bananaxxxxxxxxxgestrawberryxxxxxxxar'

for word in t:
    if word not in s1: continue
    index = -1 # Start at -1 so our index search starts at 0
    for iteration in range(s1.count(word)):
        index = s1.find(word, index+1)
        length = len(word)
        before = s2[:index]
        after = s2[index+length:]
        s2 = before + 'x'*length + after

print s2 == solution
```

Comment: Alright, builtins restriction wasn't part of the problem, because the OP mentioned using itertools (which I doubt would work anyway, since we have two reference strings).  Oh, well.

Comment: You know anything in stdlib to do that easily?

Comment: You might be able to make it shorter with re.  Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> string_ = 'bananaappleorangestrawberryapplepear'
>>> words = ('apple', 'plepe', 'leoran', 'lemon')
>>> xes = [(string_.find(w), len(w)) for w in words]
>>> xes
[(6, 5), (29, 5), (9, 6), (-1, 5)]
>>> for index, len_ in xes:
...   if index == -1: continue
...   string_ = string_.replace(string_[index:index+len_], 'x'*len_)
...
>>> string_
'bananaxxxxxxxxxgestrawberryxxxxxxxar'
>>>
```

There are surely more effective ways, but the premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ('apple', 'plepe', 'leoran', 'lemon')
b = 'bananaappleorangestrawberryapplepear'

for fruit in a:
    if a in b:
        b = b.replace(fruit, numberofx's)
```

The only thing you have to do now his determine how many X's to replace with.

Comment: This will fail since it won't assure complete coverage, e.g. 'apple' and 'plepe' overlap, but the second won't be handled.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mask_words(s, words):
    mask = [False] * len(s)
    for word in words:
        pos = 0
        while True:
            idx = s.find(word, pos)
            if idx == -1:
                break

            length = len(word)
            for i in xrange(idx, idx+length):
                mask[i] = True
            pos = idx+length

    # Sanity check:
    assert len(mask) == len(s)

    result = []
    for masked, c in zip(mask, s):
        result.append('x' if masked else c)

    return "".join(result)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is what you mean by "ugly", but it's reasonably fast and understandable.  If you're processing very large strings with few hits you could reduce memory usage somewhat by storing ranges to mask rather than a full array, but the performance here seems reasonable.

Comment: `pos = idx+length` is wrong. Only 1 should be added to the position, otherwise it will fail using `yyy` and `yyyyy`.